# Mysql Order By After Group?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Hi I have Sql Result like

[image: sql result]

My Query is like

```
SELECT sales_flat_order.entity_id AS entity_id,
      CASE
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '0' AND '100.99' THEN '0->100.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '101' AND '150.99' THEN >'101-150.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '151' AND '200.99' THEN >'151-200.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '201' AND '250.99' THEN >'201-250.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '251' AND '300.99' THEN >'251-300.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '301' AND '350.99' THEN >'301-350.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '351' AND '400.99' THEN >'351-400.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '401' AND '450.99' THEN >'401-450.99'
          WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '451' AND '500.99' THEN >'451-500.99'
          ELSE '501+'
      END AS 'order_range',
      CONCAT(MONTHNAME(sales_flat_order.created_at), ' - ', >YEAR(sales_flat_order.created_at)) AS 'Month',
      CONCAT('$', FORMAT(SUM(sales_flat_order.`grand_total`), 2)) AS 'Sales',
      sales_flat_order.`grand_total` AS Amount,
      COUNT(sales_flat_order.entity_id) AS 'Orders' 
FROM sales_flat_order GROUP BY MONTH,order_range 
ORDER BY Amount ASC
```

I need to order the result by Ascending 2nd Column 'Order Range'.

My expected answer should be like

```
Feb 2015 | 0-100  | XXX <br>
Feb 2015 | 101-150| XXX <br>
Feb 2015 | 150-200| XXX <br>
Feb 2015 | 200-250| XXX <br>
Feb 2015 | 250-300| XXX <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here:

```
ORDER BY
    Month,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(order_range, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED);
```

[image]

Here is a demo showing that this ordering logic works:

### Demo

**Edit:**

*Don't* report the year and month as text, with the month first followed by the year, because you will also just be inviting sorting problems there as well.  Instead, order using `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
ORDER BY
    DATE_FORMAT(sales_flat_order.created_at, '%Y-%m'),
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(order_range, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply , order range column is correct now, But the month column is showing like alphabetical order.    April 2015, April 2016 , Feb 2015 , Feb 2016 ...... Etc . I need month column is sorted like Feb 2015 , March 2015 , April 2015 ...... Feb 2016 , March 2016 , April 2016 ....... etc

Comment: @Radhu Did you read my updated answer?  Use `DATE_FORMAT` to build a date string with the year first followed by the month.

Comment: Tough one, I don't think I've ever seen this.  In my last update, I use the numeric year followed by the numeric month.  This has to work.

Comment: #@Tim Biegeleisen Thank you for the leads , I got it by replacing %b to %m . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your  'order by' query part with the following:

```
ORDER BY MONTH, FIELD(order_range,
'0->100.99',
'101-150.99',
'201-250.99',
...
)
```